# Cannot run bash script from crontab when it runs from command line bash

Tags: python, django, bash, ubuntu, cron

My bash script(myfile.sh) is:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd shivangi

cd hunt3
source bin/activate
cd backend_repo
sudo python manage.py runcrons
```

I am using Ubuntu 15.04

My crontab is :

```
*/1 * * * *  /home/shivangi/myfile.sh
```

Comment: Absolute paths would be a good step, as you can't guarantee it'll start in a directory where you can do `cd shivangi`.  Is `sudo` asking for a password, or is that passwordless?

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute paths in your script:

```
# /home/shivangi/myfile.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/home/shivangi/hunt3/bin/python /home/shivangi/hunt3/manage.py runcrons
```